# Using fetch API in an addon-sdk basaed extension

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to use the new [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) instead of the old XMLHttpReuest in my extension, but seems like fetch is not available in the extension's context.

I even tried to use the fetch API that is attached to the hidden window, but got an error.

```
var fetch = Cc['@mozilla.org/appshell/appShellService;1']
  .getService(Ci.nsIAppShellService).hiddenDOMWindow
  .fetch;
```

Here is the error message: `TypeError: 'fetch' called on an object that does not implement interface Window.`

So is there anyway to take advantage of this new API in an extension?

Comment: Are you sure that DOM available for hidden windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for me - assuming the new `jpm` add-on SDK

```
const { Cu } = require("chrome");
Cu.importGlobalProperties(["fetch"]);
```

now you use it just like you would in a web page

```
fetch('http://cross.origin.works.too/huzzah.html')
.then(response => response.json())
.then( //.... etc
```